# Problemas para guardar checkbox en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes hoy acudo a ustedes porque tengo un problema al momento de almacenar un checkbox ya que al momento de guardarse en la base de datos este se guarda de esta forma: 
                      `a:1:{i:0;s:4:"azul";}
lo que se debe guardar solo es la parte que dice azul, he intentado todo pero el problema persiste

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtenerlo con javascript.

```
var valueChecked = document.getElementById("acepto").checked;
```

Despues lo envías a PHP por medio de ajax o fetch para guardar el valor en la base de datos.

```
var url = "direccion donde esta tu funcion en php para guardar en BD";
var header = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: valueChecked 
}
fetch(url, header)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(function(response){
     // Respuesta del servidor
});
```